# Can't show emojis in react native #react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, emoji

I am working on an app where I have a textInput. When I deploy the app on my iphone and insert emojis, they render as a bunch of question marks. The same thing happens when I write something with keyboards other than English.
Any idea what the reason could be? Your help is highly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue was not with react, but in our database: changed the data type to nvarchar and everything works now.